# UX patterns for manual review of error messages

Tags: website-design, gui-design

I have a set of 80+ automated tests that run every morning on all the datasets in my database. Some are critical tests and some are non-critical. Any failed tests record in a DB table the dataset that failed and the test that was failed. This list of fails can be 10,000 and the list of critical fails is usually between 10 and 30 items.

I want to present the list of failure for manual review along with some action buttons like "Retest", "Ignore", and "Remove".

What common UX patterns for this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to focus initially on the information hierarchy. As I think in this case the critical errors are the ones to focus on primarily, so it's better to group them together or give a tag to it. If the test is done sequentially, then the error logs can be displayed in a timeline layout.

Display each error in a timeline layout and provide each one with an action button or link to perform the actions. As for other non-critical data, it can be displayed likewise, the user the go through them with vertical scroll.

This is how I would initially think of the layout. Let me know if you think there is flaw in this layout. Here's a visual demo:[image]

Comment: I like your idea of grouping by importance, especially since there is such a disparity in numbers.

Comment: I'm not understanding what a timeline layout gains me in this situation. The tests are on a current data state and do not have a time dependant component. Is it time based for the reviewer?

Answer (score 1):

My idea in this case was to have a timeline which records the error as they are reported, this way it becomes easy for manual viewing. Otherwise, you can have two tabs, one with critical error and other with non-critical error. Each tab can be displayed in a tabular form, with pagination having a page interval of 10, so that it's easy to navigate to the farther item. You can also provide page input field.

[image]

Comment: I like the tab idea. Thanks!